# I have extra "cells"/lines in ipad scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I am creating this app and on iPad's at the end of table I get those lines. Is there a way to see just plain gray color after table ends? I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong or I am trying to do impossible. On iPhones I don't have any problems, because the whole menu cannot fit screen so when I scroll to the bottom thats where it stops, on iPad it has to fill rest of the screen with something.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Try

```
your_tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```